# Computing an implicit limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

### Problem:

Define $f(x,y)=\frac{\arctan (xy)-x^2+3y^4}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ for $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$.

Define also $K(R)$ the best real costant such that $f(x,y) \leq K(R)$ for all $(x,y) \in \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}: x^2+y^2 \geq R^2 \}$.

Thus we have a nonincreasing function $K: ]0,+\infty] \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$.

If $a \in \mathbb{R}$, then compute $\lim\limits_{R \to 0^+} R^a K(R)$.

I really don't know where to start.

Comment: Probably best to switch to polar coordinates for the duration of the problem. Notice that if $K$ is nonincreasing, it is a reasonable assumption for some $(x,y)$ that the max would occur at the boundary $x^2+y^2 = R^2$

Comment: @NinadMunshi I tried it to, but it did not help me. Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Yes, that is why I am giving you hints. If the max occurs at the boundary, this is a $1$D optimization problem in terms of the variable $\theta$. Also notice that on the $y$ axis the function is a constant $3$. Are there any value on a circle of radius $R$ bigger than this?

Comment: @NinadMunshi I understand what you are saying. I tried to compute the 1D optimization you are talking about but it is really hard to handle. Is there a way to avoid this calculation?

Comment: There is Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I still cannot see how to proceed. Could you please add more details posting an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we only care about values near $0$ then notice that

$$\arctan(xy) - x^2 + 3y^4 \approx xy -x^2 $$

in which case the function is approximately

$$f(x,y) \approx \frac{\cos\theta\sin\theta - \cos^2\theta}{R^2}$$

$K(R)$ for this function would be $\frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2R^2}$. This would mean that $a = 2$ and

$$\lim_{R\to 0^+} R^2 K(R) = \frac{\sqrt{2}-1}{2}$$

All that's left to show is that this $K(R)$ for the approximation dominates the $K(R)$ for the function for small enough $R$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Actually I am not sure about you first statement: $\arctan(xy) - x^2 + 3y^4 \approx xy$. Shouldn't be $\arctan(xy) - x^2 + 3y^4 \approx xy-x^2$? The second part is clear, I understood your idea.

Comment: @FilippoGiovagnini Beat you to it, I already fixed the error :)

Comment: Now it is clear, thank you so much!

Comment: @FilippoGiovagnini optimizing with $\theta$ was a pain which is why it took me so long to type up the fix. I recommend using Lagrange multipliers at this step instead when you get to it.

Comment: @ProfessorVector I just confirmed with Lagrange multipliers that it is indeed $-$ and not $+$. Your mistake was in your cosine double angle identity, the sign is incorrect.

Comment: I'm sorry! You're correct, of course.